# How to make a Windows Store package for Insider builds only?

Tags: windows-store, desktop-bridge, appxmanifest

I am trying to give Windows Insider users a different version of my app. In **Package.appxmanifest** I specify:

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17754.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.17755.0" />
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17754.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.17755.0" />
```

However, when I built it, and uploaded to Package flights of my app, the Packages section shows

> Device families   Windows.Universal min version 10.0.14393.0 ,
>   Windows.Desktop min version 10.0.14393.0

And when I published it, my machine with 17134 still received the update.

The app is a Desktop Bridge app.

Is this a limitation of Desktop Bridge apps, some bug, or, unlike Android, Windows does not let you make different packages for different versions of Windows 10?

Comment: Could you check your project property if there is 17755 target version can be targeted? Because the  latest sdk insider preview version is 17749.  if your just modify the appxmanifest file, it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nico Zhu - MSFT suggested in the comment: looks like Desktop Bridge's Store Packaging **project's properties** override what I put into **Package.appxmanifest**. The min version seems now to be correct after updating it in project properties.

However I still can't upload to the Store, but this time due to a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Device families Windows.Universal min version 10.0.14393.0 , Windows.Desktop min version 10.0.14393.0

The problem may there is no Windows 10 SDK version(17755) in your system, and the min windows 10 version in your system is 14393.

You could not target both min and max Version to 17755. Currently the latest insider [preview SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK?wa=wsignin1.0) version is 17749. if you just modify the appxmanifest file, it will not work.

Comment: So I tried to do that, and I got the following message:
"Package acceptance validation error: The package Store_2.1.12.0_AnyCPU.appx uses an unsupported version of file MakePri.exe (10.0.17749.1000). The following versions are allowed: < 10.0.10500.0; >= 10.0.10586.0 & < 10.0.11000.0; >= 10.0.14383.0 & < 10.0.14800.0; >= 10.0.15053.0 & < 10.0.15100.0; >= 10.0.16299.0 & < 10.0.16350.0; >= 10.0.17134.0 & < 10.0.17500.0. Please update your Visual Studio build tools and try again." So looks like I can only target 17500, but not 177xx?